# Assigning form-control a default from returned backend data

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, form-control

I'm having trouble assigning my form-control default value to a number I'm getting from the backend.

I've saved the number into it's own object and am trying to call for it in the form control.

```
totalInvoice: number;

finalizeInvoiceCost = this.fb.group({
   totalInvoiceCost: [this.totalInvoice]
});
```

I expect the form-control to default to the number stored inside totalInvoice but when i log it to the console it shows a value of 'null'

Comment: It would be nice to see a bit more code than that. Is that inside of your ngOnInit? Is totalInvoice populated after a delay or passed in as the component is created?

Comment: Populated after a delay. I set the value of totalInvoice after running some logic on a returned piece of data

Comment: So if I understand correctly you initialize the formGroup first and then after a delay you set totalInvoice value?

Comment: Yes. Now that I think about it, I need to set the form control value after I set the invoiceTotal during the initialization. Right? How would I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, after you initialize `totalInvoice` you can set its value in the form like:

```
this.finalizeInvoiceCost.patchValue({totalInvoiceCost: this.totalInvoice});
```

You can also use `setValue` but for that you must give a value to every field in your form or it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the formBuilder to set a default value for you control like so:

```
finalizeInvoiceCost = this.fb.group({
    totalInvoiceCost:  this.fb.control(this.totalInvoice, [])
});
```

That's if you already have that `totalInvoice` initialized.
If you don't then you can that later by calling:

`this.finalizeInvoiceCost.get('totalInvoiceCost').patchValue(this.someNewValue);`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe formControl getting 'totalInvoice' with default value 'null', because your 'totalInvoice' haven't received data from backend.

First you must make sure the 'totalInvoice' have data.

Or you can use this, after 'totalInvoicesCost' have a data.

```
this.finalizeInvoiceCost.get('totalInvoiceCost').setValue(totalInvoice);
```